# Custom toolWindow is not showing it's context

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm creating custom toolWindow and add it to my userControl. UserControl is an element for custom dockingWindows and toolWindows. So in my mainWindow xaml I have DataTemplate

`<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:PropertyGridToolWindowViewModel}">
                <views:PropertyGridToolWindowView/>

            </DataTemplate>`

And I'm setting my userControl that holds all toolWindows and DocumentWindows like:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding}" x:Name="CustomContentControl"/>
```

My custom toolWindow xaml code looks like:

```
<Grid>
    <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Dock="Right">
        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Dock="Top" >
            <Grid>
                <Button Name="SaveBtn" Content="    Save    " IsEnabled="{Binding SaveButtonIsEnabled}" Grid.Column="0" Command="{Binding SaveClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=PropertiesUserControl}"/>
                <Button Name="EditBtn" Content="    Edit    " Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Command="{Binding EditClickCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding EditButtonIsEnabled}"/>
                <Button Name="CancelBtn" Content="   Cancel   " Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Command="{Binding CancelClickCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding CancelButtonIsEnabled}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Dock="Bottom">
            <shared:PixelSnapper>
                <propgrid:PropertyGrid SelectedObject="{Binding SelectedObject}">
                </propgrid:PropertyGrid>
            </shared:PixelSnapper>
        </DockPanel>
    </DockPanel>


</Grid>
```

And my customUserControl for toolWindows and documentWindows is:

```
  <docking:DockSite x:Name="dockSite" viewModels:DockSiteViewModelBehavior.IsManaged="true" CanDocumentWindowsRaft="True" ItemContainerRetentionMode="Wrapped"
                      DocumentItemsSource="{Binding DocumentItems}" DocumentItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource DocumentItemStyle}"
                      ToolItemsSource="{Binding ToolItems}" ToolItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ToolItemStyle}">
      <docking:DockSite.AutoHideRightContainers>
            <docking:ToolWindowContainer>
                <views:PropertyGridToolWindow CanClose="False" HasOptions="False"/>
            </docking:ToolWindowContainer>
       </docking:DockSite.AutoHideRightContainers>

       <docking:Workspace x:Name="Workspace>
            <docking:TabbedMdiHost />
        </docking:Workspace>
    </docking:DockSite>
```

As you can see, I'm adding toolWindow in xaml and it's displaying in a right way. But I need to create this toolWindow dynamically. And there is the problem. When I create the same toolWindow dynamically, it is not diplaying dockpanel of my custom toolWindow. How can I solve this issue?
Thanks in advance

**Edit** the way I create toolWindows

```
var toolWindow = new PropertyGridToolWindowViewModel();
toolWindow.Title = "Another ToolWindow";
_toolItems.Add(toolWindow);
```

The problem is that the view is not created. But I cannot understand why...

Comment: How are you creating the `ToolWindow` dynamically? Please show your code.

Comment: Ok, I found error, but thanks for help anyway.

Comment: Have you solved you problem now?

Comment: can you please add an answer with your solution and then accept it as the correct answer to help other users that may come across your post looking for a solution to similar problems?

Comment: yes sure, I will do it later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've deleted this code:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:PropertyGridToolWindowViewModel}"> 
<views:PropertyGridToolWindowView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

from my mainWindowXaml. Then I decided to create my window following way:

```
var toolWindow = new PropertyGridToolWindowView();
_toolItems.Add(toolWindow);
```

And in constructor of my view I've created my viewModel and it solved the problem.